# Passing checkbox array to GAS?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am using Google App Script to create an HTML sidebar in Sheets. I want to have several checkboxes to select and pass the values back to GAS, preferably as an array. I have been looking up solutions and [was using this](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-get-all-checked-checkbox-value-in-javascript) as a guide. Here is my GAS code:

```
function showSidebar() {
  var array = ["A","B","C","D","E"];

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('page');
  html.cols = array;

  var html = html.evaluate().setTitle('Example');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
    .showSidebar(html);
}

function displayToast(columns) {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Output: " + columns);
}
```

The toast is there to test my setup, but it doesn't display when I click the submit button.

Here is the 'page' HTML:

```
<body>
    <p>Which columns should be included in the email?</p>
    <? for(var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="col" id="<?= cols[i] ?>" value="<?= cols[i] ?>">Col
    <?= cols[i] ?></input>
    <? } ?><br>
    <button id="btn">Submit</button> <br>
</body>

<script>
  document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var markedCheckbox = document.getElementsByName('col');
   google.script.run.displayToast(markedCheckbox);
 }
</script>
```

The sidebar displays correctly, but I just can't get the checkbox values to pass over to the GAS side.
TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the HTML element to Apps Script. You have to send only the values:

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var markedCheckbox = Array.from(document.getElementsByName('col'))
    .filter(x => x.checked)
    .map(x => x.value)

  google.script.run.displayToast(markedCheckbox);
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't work, either. My execution log doesn't show "displayToast" as having run so I assume there is something in the HTML/script that is malfunctioning?

Comment: @TeedFerguson the only thing you need to change is the content in the <script> tag, the rest should stay the same no problem